# Table name is not showing for the Database data Block in Oracle Apps Custom Form FMB

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a Oracle Apps Custom Form. In that Form I want to know from which table the database block getting data for form.

So I right click the DATA BLOCK-->property palette-->Database Block. In the database Block =yes/Query data source is Null. No table name is Showing. How can I find the table name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a binary logic for determining the data source. The table name in the ***Data Source*** part has priority in case *Database Block* option set to **Yes** as you already checked for.

Otherwise(in case *Data Source* is *null*), the ***Block Name*** will be considered as the data source name, eg. a *table* or *view* name within the currently connected schema, provided again that the *Database Block* option set to **Yes**

Another case that you might have a **query** , presumably within a **trigger** of forms, populating the fields under that block.

Comment: thanks For your reply Barbaros
I tried that Also,tried to run the select query in sql developer using block name as a table name .It shows error table or view does not exists.I also tried to check the last query in the front that method also showing no queries

Comment: Yes @barbaros I found a procedure in the Program units. Thanks For Your reply

Comment: you're welcome @AshokAnburaj good luck!